# Keyboard flashes after Navigator.push

Tags: flutter

I have Flutter app. On first screen it has 2 TextFields and Next button.
I input some text to these TextFields and click on empty space to hide keyboard and press Next. Next button doing something like this:

```
await Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    settings: // ...
  )
)
```

After I press Next button keyboard appears and immediately disappears.

After some debugging, I assume that this happens cause Flutter called method didPush() from
flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart, which do requestFocus() on my TextField:

```
abstract class Route<T> {    
      /// Called after [install] when the route is pushed onto the navigator.
      TickerFuture didPush() {
        return TickerFuture.complete()..then<void>((void _) {
          navigator?.focusScopeNode.requestFocus();
        });
      }    
}
```

How to figure out why the keyboard flushes and avoid this behavior?

Comment: on empty space are you using FocusScope.of(context).unfocus() for keyboard hide?

Comment: @RohitChaurasiya no, I mean just tap by finger on some space where is no TextInput

Comment: check below code for close keyboard.

Comment: @RohitChaurasiya in my case the keyboard is hidden, and no reason to close it. Just in the moment of pressing Next button it appears and immediately disappears

Comment: @RohitChaurasiya Flutter team confirms that this is framework issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94249